# Tcl: catch errors from all commands

Tags: error-handling, tcl

Sorry, I couldn't come up with a better title. My problems is the following: If I execute a Tcl `proc`, I can wrap the execution in `catch` to catch and process errors. I do this in my code to have the same error output everywhere. However, my program provides numerous `proc`s which the user can use in scripts (mostly at the outermost level), and it would be cumbersome if the user would have to wrap every one of them in a `catch`. I could of course use an additional level of indirection in each of those commands, but I wanted to ask whether there is a way to `catch` errors from *all* commands executed, without explicitly using `catch` on each invocation?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Short answer: No. You should use 'catch' inside each proc (where needed) instead of catch(ing) every call to a proc.

Comment: Expected errors are part of the API to be documented to the users of your procs. You should actively promote them and make sure that that users properly deal with them (ideally, you provide some `errorcode` so that users can `trap` them using their `try` commands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Read this paragraph first: ↓

The single most important principle of error handling is **don't throw away errors unless you *know for sure* that that's the correct way to handle them.** Doing so just because they're unsightly is *very bad!* (Logging them is far better.)

---

The closest you can get is to run the whole of your existing code inside a `catch` or `try`. You can put a `source` inside that, so a little driver script to retrofit on existing code is just something like:

```
set argc [llength [set argv [lassign $argv argv0]]]
catch {source $argv0}
```

Assuming you're applying it during the call to the overall script. You also might need to set up `interp bgerror`:

```
interp bgerror {} {apply {{msg opt} {
    if {[lindex [dict get $opt -errorcode] 0] eq "EXPECTED"} {
        # Ignore this
    } else {
        # Unexpected error; better tell the user
        puts "ERROR: $msg"
        puts [dict get $opt -errorinfo]
    }
}}}
```

*It's not a really good idea to do this though.* If you hide all the errors, how will you find and fix any errors? Using `try` is better, since that lets you hide only expected errors:

```
try {
    source $argv0
} trap EXPECTED {} {
    # Ignore this
}
```

and I'd probably wrap things up so that I have local variables:

```
apply {{} {
    global argv0 argv argc
    set argc [llength [set argv [lassign $argv argv0]]]
    try {
        uplevel #0 [list source $argv0]
    } trap EXPECTED {msg} {
        # Log this; the logging engine is out of scope for the question
        log DEBUG $msg
    }
}}
```

You'll need to experiment to see what to `trap`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution using `source` is elegant, but doesn't really fit for my purpose (the user script is run directly from the command line, I don't think I can wrap it). I went for the solution to wrap the body of all user procs in a `do {... }`, where `do` is a `proc` which uses `catch {uplevel $cmd...}` to catch the errors and print error information (btw., no errors are ignored in my code). One just has to test for result 1 of `catch` to prevent the error mechanism being triggered by `return`, `break` and so on.

Comment: One advantage of using try is that it does the result code testing for you. It's also possible to put this sort of thing on the C side by writing your own top level main loop; standard tclsh doesn't give you the chance to do that as it stands. (Perhaps it should…)

Comment: Thanks, I switched to `try` anyhow since I forgot that I have to pass through return values from the `do` blocks, and I didn't manage to do this with `catch`.